# Set xacro arguments when parsing a file using Python (ROS2)

Tags: python, ros2, urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to set arguments when parsing a file using the python xacro library?

In ROS2, a number of packages parse xacro files directly in the launch file using the python xacro library, with something along the lines of:

```
import xacro, os

xacro_file = "test.urdf.xacro"
doc = xacro.parse(open(xacro_file))
xacro.process_doc(doc)
robot_description_config = doc.toxml()
robot_description = {'robot_description': robot_description_config}
```

For some context, say I have a file, `test.urdf.xacro` that takes an argument named `input`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="test" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <xacro:arg name="input" defaut="default"/>
    <link name="$(arg input)"/>
</robot>
```

Using the python code above, the argument would be the default value and the link would be named `default`. But how can you pass in a custom value?

Using the command line interface, f I wanted to parse the file with some custom value, I could simply type the following in the terminal:

```
$ xacro test.urdf.xacro input:="new_input"
```

and get an output where my link is appropriately named `new_input`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from test.urdf.xacro                | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot name="test">
  <link name="new_input"/>
</robot>
```

But I'm at a loss when it comes to achieving the same directly using python. Anyone have any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385238/set-xacro-arguments-when-parsing-a-file-using-python-(ros2)/) by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1567 on 2021-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to JafarAbdi/PickNik's [parameter_tools](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/parameter_tools/blob/main/parameter_builder/example/example_node.py) package for the inspiration.

For anyone interested in adding arguments while parsing xacro files using the python library, you can either use his tool or to set the "mappings" argument when calling `xacro.process_file()`, e.g.:

```
# load xacro file with `input` set to `new_input`
robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file, mappings={"input": "new_input"}).toxml()
robot_description = {'robot_description': robot_description_config}
```

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-08**:\

> Thanks to JafarAbdi's [parameter_tools](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/parameter_tools/blob/main/parameter_builder/example/example_node.py) package, there's now a clean way to load xacro files with argument inputs.

tbh, I would depending on a 3rd party package for something which seems like it should be core functionality not "a clean way".

That's not to say it can't be a solution to your problem of course.

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-09-08**:
I've edited the answer to clarify - I more intended to give credit to the tool where I found the answer. That said, while I agree with your sentiment, it does seem like a good workaround to a number of common problems that have been *slow* to get addressed in the *core* and so, as things stand, for many this package would represent a "clean" solution. I would love to see equivalent functionality in the core set of launch tools and it does look like many aspects are on the horizon. But some of us are impatient :)